# nginx not displaying correct page when navigating to www.domain.com ok when just domain.com

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, gunicorn, amazon-lightsail

I'm trying to deploy nginx / gunicorn / flask on ubuntu and all seems to be working when I navigate to "domain.com" but when i go to "www.domain.com" i get the defualt splash screen for nginx.

nginx is setup as below.

```
server {
 server_name thecomputermade.me www.thecomputermade.me;
location / {
include proxy_params;
proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ubuntu/imageRate/imageRate.sock;
}

listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/thecomputermade.me/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/thecomputermade.me/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot



}
server {
if ($host = thecomputermade.me) {
return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
} # managed by Certbot


listen 80;
server_name thecomputermade.me;
return 404; # managed by Certbot
```

}

when i run `systemctl status nginx` I get the the below.

```
 nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2020-11-16 08:54:05 UTC; 999ms ago
       Docs: man:nginx(8)
    Process: 1430 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 1442 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 1443 (nginx)
      Tasks: 2 (limit: 560)
     Memory: 2.9M
     CGroup: /system.slice/nginx.service
             ├─1443 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on;
             └─1444 nginx: worker process

Nov 16 08:54:05 ip-172-26-6-186 systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
Nov 16 08:54:05 ip-172-26-6-186 nginx[1430]: nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "www.thecomputermade.me" on 0.0.0.0:443, ignored
Nov 16 08:54:05 ip-172-26-6-186 nginx[1442]: nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "www.thecomputermade.me" on 0.0.0.0:443, ignored
Nov 16 08:54:05 ip-172-26-6-186 systemd[1]: Started A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
```

Notice the line where it says conflicting server name...

I've tried just thecomputermade.me in the nginx config:

- "thecomputermade.me" works as expected but again "www.thecomputermade.me" navigates to the defualt splash screen of nginx.

When I add only "www.thecomputermade.me" in the config:

- both addresses navigate the the default splash and i get the conflicting server name warning.

Does anyone know what I need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I've worked it out.

First I ran  `sudo grep -r www.thecomputermade.me /etc/nginx` this showed up multiple references to this domain.

And this means, as the error said. There were conflicting server names.

Why did it happen?

Turns out the certbot adds some data into the "default" config file in `/etc/nginix/sites-available`.

To fix this I commented out all the lines relating to "www.thecomputermade.me" in the default config file and , hey presto, it works.

Hope this helps someone else in the future.